# Setting the current tab onload dynamically in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I currently have 6 tabs in my Kendo TabStrip..

All works fine but, when the page loads I want to show the 3rd tab first?

Does anyone have any examples?

I looked around for a while now and searching the docs but no luck..

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the particular tab which you want to show when the page loads, with the class
    "k-state-active".
Refer http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/tabstrip/overview#select-a-tab-on-initial-load

Answer (score 0):

To change your tab dynamically, do the following..

First, remove the default "k-state-active" within your HTML page then add the following JS code:

```
    function changeTabDynamically(tabIndex) {
        $("#tab").data("kendoTabStrip").select(tabIndex);
    }
```